# Angular, Ag Grid - Flashcells styling based on data

Tags: ag-grid

I am using ag-grid to display stock prices. These prices get updated at real time through a feed.

- I am using `gridApi.updateRowData()` to update rows accordingly.
- And `gridApi.flashCells()` to flash whenever there are updates.
- I have set `enableCellChangeFlash="true"` in the html.

This setup is working fine. The rows flash when there are changes in data.

My requirement is if the incoming price is below a threshold price, i need the flash color to be red, and if its above threshold price, the flash color to be green.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you [can override `styles`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52665616/grid-styling-overwrite-style-of-ag-grid/52672411#52672411) the default *flash-color* on your case

```
.ag-theme-balham .ag-cell-data-changed {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Another possible way is to use [an existing approach](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/#animate-renderer):

> **`agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer`**: The previous value is temporarily shown beside the old value with a directional arrow showing increase or decrease in value. The old value is then faded out.
>
> **`agAnimateSlideCellRenderer`**: The previous value shown in a faded fashion and slides, giving a ghosting effect as the old value fades and slides away.

```
cellRenderer: "agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer"
```

and the third one is to create own, custom `cellRenderer` - but, it would be a complicated solution I suppose.

Comment: Thanks @un-spike for your comment. However, overriding default style will not help for me because I want it conditionally. Iverriding would make it default red. I want red only if the price drops down. Else it should be green. Do you know of any such trick? Also "agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer" will animate the cell only. I would need the entire row to be flashed with the respective color.