# AG-grid - angular6 - color change for flashing on grid refresh

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using

```
 [enableCellChangeFlash]="true"
```

and doing

```
  var params = { force: true };
  this.gridApi.refreshCells(params);
```

for force refresh of all cells.

The Flash refresh is happening but the color is green or Greenish.
Is there a way to change this default color how?

Example can be seen here :https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-refresh/

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the plunk I've created: [Refresh Cells - override color](https://plnkr.co/edit/35HW1FsBZ0yRCtSE3gSy?p=preview)

You need to update the CSS

```
.ag-theme-balham-dark .ag-row .ag-cell-data-changed {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Simply `.ag-theme-balham-dark .ag-cell-data-changed { ... }` won't work because [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) applies the styles having `!important`. We also need to override it.

Answer (score 2):

based on [my another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52672411/4483102)

```
styles: [`
    .ag-theme-balham-dark .ag-cell-data-changed {
        background-color:red !important;
    }
`],
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/zKwbnFK5FW4e31e98jYd?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me:

```
.ag-value-change-value-highlight {
 background-color:red !important;
}
```